# I'm trying to record date and time from local into .csv file but it displays `,` in between every character

Tags: python, csv, datetime

I'm trying to record the date and time every second into .csv file (for making a live graph in the future). According to my code, the following result is displayed `,` in between every character. Is there a way to get rid of them?

Thank you in advance for any solutions.

Here's my code

```
import csv
import time


def processing_loop(csvfile):
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    
    while True:
       
        localtime = time.localtime()
        result = time.strftime("%c", localtime)
        csv_writer.writerow(result)
        csvfile.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

with open('results.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    processing_loop(csvfile)
```

The result shown in my .csv file.

```
M,o,n, ,J,u,l, ,1,9, ,1,5,:,2,8,:,4,0, ,2,0,2,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writerow expects something it can iterate ... it can iterate a string, making each letter a column

just make sure you give it a list

```
csv_writer.writerow([result])
```